# Aurelia. Testing. TypeError: config.addPipelineStep is not a function

Tags: javascript, testing, aurelia

I use default Aurelia's [sceleton-esnext](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/releases/tag/1.0.0-beta.3.0.1) updated to last version . 
I added this line to App (
[Example from doc. Customizing the Navigation Pipeline](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/7))

```
config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep);
```

After this I catch error running 'gulp test'

```
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Linux 0.0.0) the App module contains a router property FAILED
TypeError: config.addPipelineStep is not a function
```

Test

```
  it('contains a router property', () => {
    expect(sut.router).toBeDefined();
  });
```

Test is going well without line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came across this issue. To fix, you just need to add an empty method into your RouterStub:

```
class RouterStub {
    configure(handler) {
        handler(this);
    }

    map(routes) {
        this.routes = routes;
    }

    addPipelineStep(stepName, stepClass) {
    }
}
```

then in your test:

```
describe('the App module', () => {
    var app;
    var mockedRouter;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockedRouter = new RouterStub();
        app = new App();
        app.configureRouter(mockedRouter, mockedRouter);
    });

    it('contains a router property', () => {
        expect(app.router).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

If you're trying to test the pipeline step you'll need to mock the router itself and test the actual logic, but if you just want your tests to run (i.e. be defined, check the router title etc), this will work.